# I am receiving json object but retrofits sees it like array?

Tags: android, json, retrofit

Error occurred when parsing JSON. This is my error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY
```

My JSON :

```
    {  
   "statusCode":200,
     "message":"success",
       "result":[  {  
         "user_id":1,    "title":"some title",
         "address":"some address",
         "from_hours":"09:00",
         "to_hours":"20:00",
         "min_price":5000,
      },{  
         "user_id":4,    "title":"some title",
         "address":"some address",
         "from_hours":"09:00",
         "to_hours":"20:00",
         "min_price":5000,
      }
   ]
}
```

Here is my my interface:

```
        @GET(ApiEndpoint.SEARCH_PROVIDERS)
        Single<Providers> searchProviders(@Query("name") String name);
```

My network request:

```
 RxSearchObservable.fromView(name)
                .debounce(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                 .filter(new Predicate<String>() {
                  @Override
                    public boolean test(String text) throws Exception {
                       if (text.isEmpty()) {
                          return false;
                        } else {
                           Log.d("rx", "accept: not empty");
                          return true;
                     }
                  }
            })
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .switchMapSingle(new Function<String, Single<Providers>>() {
                @Override
                public Single<Providers> apply(String s) throws Exception {
                    Log.d("rx", "accept: switchMapSingle");
                    return getDataManager().getApiHelper().searchProviders(s)
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
                }
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Consumer<Providers>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(Providers result) throws Exception {
                    Log.d("rx", "accept: subscribe");
                        getMvpView().onResultList(result.getResult());
                }
            }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(@NonNull Throwable throwable)
                        throws Exception {
                    if (!isViewAttached()) {
                        return;
                    }

                    getMvpView().showMessage(AppMessages.ERROR_OCCURED);
                    Log.d("rx", "accept: "+throwable.getMessage());

                    getMvpView().hideLoading();

                    // handle the error here
                    if (throwable instanceof ANError) {
                        ANError anError = (ANError) throwable;
                        handleApiError(anError);
                    }
                }
            });
```

I don't understand what caused the error.

My Providers.java class

```
public class Providers implements Parcelable {
@SerializedName("statusCode")
@Expose
private Integer statusCode;
@SerializedName("message")
@Expose
private String message;
@SerializedName("result")
@Expose
private Result result;
public final static Parcelable.Creator<Providers> CREATOR = new Creator<Providers>() {


    @SuppressWarnings({
            "unchecked"
    })
    public Providers createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Providers(in);
    }

    public Providers[] newArray(int size) {
        return (new Providers[size]);
    }

}
        ;

protected Providers(Parcel in) {
    this.statusCode = ((Integer) in.readValue((Integer.class.getClassLoader())));
    this.message = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
    this.result = ((Result) in.readValue((Result.class.getClassLoader())));
}

/**
 * No args constructor for use in serialization
 *
 */
public Providers() {
}

/**
 *
 * @param message
 * @param statusCode
 * @param result
 */
public Providers(Integer statusCode, String message, Result result) {
    super();
    this.statusCode = statusCode;
    this.message = message;
    this.result = result;
}

public Integer getStatusCode() {
    return statusCode;
}

public void setStatusCode(Integer statusCode) {
    this.statusCode = statusCode;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public Result getResult() {
    return result;
}

public void setResult(Result result) {
    this.result = result;
}

public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeValue(statusCode);
    dest.writeValue(message);
    dest.writeValue(result);
}

public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

}
```

Comment: Post Providers class

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: change result to List<Result> in provider class

Comment: Thanks, Ramees Thattarath. You saved my day!

Comment: I'm glad that my suggestion was helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your POJO Class is Expecting an Object of **result** but there is Array Coming  from Server

So you should Change your **MyProviders.java class** like this

```
public class Providers implements Parcelable {
@SerializedName("statusCode")
@Expose
private Integer statusCode;
@SerializedName("message")
@Expose
private String message;
@SerializedName("result")
@Expose
private List<Result> result; // change this line
public final static Parcelable.Creator<Providers> CREATOR = new Creator<Providers>() {


    @SuppressWarnings({
            "unchecked"
    })
    public Providers createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Providers(in);
    }

    public Providers[] newArray(int size) {
        return (new Providers[size]);
    }

};

protected Providers(Parcel in) {
    this.statusCode = ((Integer) in.readValue((Integer.class.getClassLoader())));
    this.message = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
    this.result = ((Result) in.readValue((Result.class.getClassLoader())));
}

/**
 * No args constructor for use in serialization
 */
public Providers() {
}

/**
 * @param message
 * @param statusCode
 * @param result
 */
public Providers(Integer statusCode, String message, Result result) {
    super();
    this.statusCode = statusCode;
    this.message = message;
    this.result = result;
}

public Integer getStatusCode() {
    return statusCode;
}

public void setStatusCode(Integer statusCode) {
    this.statusCode = statusCode;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public List<Result> getResult() {
    return result;
}

public void setResult(List<Result> result) {
    this.result = result;
}

public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeValue(statusCode);
    dest.writeValue(message);
    dest.writeValue(result);
}

public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks, scienticious! That was the issue!